# What is the inverse function of $\alpha\mathrm{e}^{\beta x}+\gamma\mathrm{e}^{\delta x}$?

Tags: logarithms

I need to solve this equation for $x$: $\alpha\mathrm{e}^{\beta x}+\gamma\mathrm{e}^{\delta x}=\epsilon$

($\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$, $\delta$, $\epsilon$ are real constants)

I'm only interested in real solutions.

Is such an equation solvable? Even Wolfram|Alpha refuses to solve trivialized versions of this equation: [$\mathrm{e}^{\alpha x}+\mathrm{e}^{\beta x}=a$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Solve%5BE%5E(alpha*x)%2BE%5E(beta*x)%3D%3Da,x%5D) or [$\alpha^x+\beta^x=a$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Solve%5Balpha%5Ex%2Bbeta%5Ex%3D%3Da,x%5D)

Comment: Functions of this form are not necessarily injective.

Comment: @aventurin Looks like [this one](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/qrqidwfcm3) is.

Answer (score 3):

Letting $z = \alpha e^{\beta x}/\epsilon$, and assuming the parameters are positive, the equation becomes 
$$ z + \dfrac{\gamma \epsilon^{\delta/\beta-1}}{\alpha^{\delta/\beta}} z^{\delta/\beta} - 1 = 0$$
which I'll write as
$$ z + c z^p - 1 = 0 $$

This has a series solution in powers of $c$, that should converge for small $|c|$:

$$\eqalign{z &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \dfrac{((-c)^n}{n!} \prod_{j=0}^{n-2} (np - j)\cr
&= 1 - c + p c^2 - \dfrac{3p(3p-1)}{6} c^3 + \dfrac{(4p)(4p-1)(4p-2)}{24} c^4 + \ldots}$$

Answer (score 1):

As already said in comments and answers, in the most general case, equations such that $$\alpha\mathrm{e}^{\beta x}+\gamma\mathrm{e}^{\delta x}=\epsilon$$ will not show analytical solutions and numerical methods would be required. The exceptions would correspond to situations where the ratio $\frac \beta \delta$ or $\frac  \delta \beta $ would be a small $(<4)$ whole number.

Assuming all constants to be positive, the function $$f(x)=\alpha\mathrm{e}^{\beta x}+\gamma\mathrm{e}^{\delta x}-\epsilon$$ varies very fast and locating the root could be difficult. On the other hand, considering $$g(x)=\log(\alpha\mathrm{e}^{\beta x}+\gamma\mathrm{e}^{\delta x})-\log(\epsilon)$$ could be much more convenient since the plot of the new function will look (more or less) to a straight line.

For illustration purposes, let us consider the case of $$f(x)=123 e^{\pi x}+456 e^{e x}-123456789$$ and 
$$g(x)=\log(123 e^{\pi x}+456 e^{ex})-\log(123456789)$$ In both cases, a plot of the function reveals that the solution is close to $x_0=4$. So, let us use Newton method starting at this value.

Using $f(x)$, the iterates will be 
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 4.3640459464006870 \\
 2 & 4.2648712725384999 \\
 3 & 4.2468522386110215 \\
 4 & 4.2463481388110046 \\
 5 & 4.2463477579278545 \\
 6 & 4.2463477579276373 
\end{array}
\right)$$
Using $g(x)$, the iterates will be 
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 4.2467859955218309 \\
 2 & 4.2463477592885205 \\
 3 & 4.2463477579276374 
 \end{array}
\right)$$

Using $g(x)$ with $x_0=0$ gives as a first estimate $x_1=4.367$.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't possible to find a general solution. Letting $y = e^x$, we have
$$\alpha y^\beta + \gamma y^\delta = \epsilon$$
Even for some integer values of $\alpha, ...,\epsilon$, this could give us polynomials whose solutions cannot be expressed in terms of ordinary operations (addition, subtraction, multiplication, division, and roots). For example, the roots of
$$y^5-4y=1$$
can't be expressed in terms of ordinary mathematical operations, since it's irreducible and it has three real roots and two complex roots, and thus has Galois group $S_5$. And so if we can't find a solution for this special case, certainly there won't be a general solution.

Comment: It can't be expressed in terms of radicals, but it can in terms of special functions.

Comment: Since this question pops up with amazing regularity on various math. fora, I'll include the link to the relevant AoPS thread here: http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h436858